# How can I disable cron for Debian?

Tags: debian, cron

I want to disable `cron` temporarily on Debian. As in, shut it down completely, so that it doesn't start up even on reboot. How can I do this?

My current use case is that I want to shut down `cron` as part of a process for moving my system to new disks.

NOTE: I don't want to edit individual `cron` files.

Comment: excellent, thanks. In that case, assuming Jessie and systemd, Stephen's answer should be fine. I don't remember if anacron is part of Debian's default install (I think it was) but disabling it if installed should finish the job.

Comment: @muru: `anacron` is "Priority: optional" on Debian, so no. And yes, the systemd command would work for jessie or later. But Stephen's answer also covers `sysvinit`.

Answer (score 18):

With systemd:

```
sudo systemctl disable cron
```

If you want to disable the daemon and stop it:

```
sudo systemctl disable cron
sudo systemctl stop cron
```

(Usually you’d expect `sudo systemctl disable cron --now` to do the trick, but apparently it doesn’t for `cron`, for some reason.)

With `sysvinit`:

```
sudo update-rc.d cron disable
sudo service cron stop
```

All these have corresponding `enable` variants to re-enable the service.

Comment: Stephen, a belated comment. I actually tried this just now. But after I run `systemctl disable cron --now` the cron daemon is still visible. I.e. `root      1239  0.0  0.0  29972  2332 ?        Ss   02:00   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f`. And looks the same as before the disable.

Comment: And after running `systemctl disable cron --now`, `systemctl status cron` shows "Active: active (running)...". So either I'm missing something, or this command does not actually stop the daemon.

Comment: @Faheem you’re right, it doesn’t. It seems to just sync state with the `sysvinit` setup, even though `cron` has a systemd-native unit.

Comment: Hi Stephen. Yes, I've come to the conclusion that it doesn't as well. And neither does fetchmail. What's a systemd-native unit?

Comment: @Faheem `cron` contains `/lib/systemd/system/cron.service` which fully defines the service, so with systemd there isn’t any need for `/etc/init.d/cron`.

Comment: I see. So this is something the maintainers can choose to add. Or not, presumably.

Comment: Yes. I wouldn’t expect it to have this impact on behaviour though.

Comment: I am on jessie I can't find `systemctl`. Is it the correct tool, what package is it in?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor if you don’t have `systemctl`, you’re not using systemd, so the second part of the answer applies (“With `sysvinit`”).

Answer (score 12):

You can `mask` the `cron` service using:

```
systemctl mask cron
```

Or to `unmask` and enable `cron` :

```
systemctl unmask cron && systemctl enable cron
```

A masked service is one whose unit file is a symlink to `/dev/null`, this makes it "impossible" to load the service, even if it is required by another enabled service.

Comment: What does `mask` do, exactly?

Comment: A masked service is one whose unit file is a symlink to /dev/null. This makes it "impossible" to load the service, even if it is required by another, enabled service. However, if you want to unmask it, you can use : `systemctl unmask cron`

Comment: Interesting. I'd not heard of this before - I suppose it's some `systemd` thing.

Comment: if you want a more detailed answer : https://askubuntu.com/a/816378/680673